# What is the simplest secure way to authenticate users via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, google-app-engine

I'm building a Google App Engine web app, with a Java back end, that relies heavily on JavaScript/JQuery in the browser (you can see it [here](http://lastcalc.com/)).

I want to implement a user authentication mechanism, that will also rely on AJAX (ie. they will be able to register and login without a page refresh).

I don't want to rely on Google's authentication because I've found that a lot of people are reluctant to give up their GMail email addresses, but I would like to support authentication via Google/Facebook/Twitter etc in future.

I like the simplicity of Reddit's approach to user authentication.

My concern is that since people won't be using my app over HTTPS, I don't want to have to send a password in clear-text over HTTP.  I would also prefer to rely on some kind of secret token (perhaps a hash of the password and some server-provided "salt"), which could be intercepted and spoofed.

At the same time, I don't want to have to put a huge amount of effort into implementing the authentication mechanism.

Is there an approach that gives me the simplicity I want, yet which is secure over HTTP?

*edit:* I just realized that Google App Engine does support HTTPS but only if you connect via the *.appspot.com URL for your site.  Unfortunately you can't do AJAX calls to this due to cross-site scripting restrictions - although I guess it may be possible with JSONP.

So, is using JSONP+HTTPS+*.appspot.com the best approach here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use https for secure communication via http.  There is no way to do secure communication from a browser without it.

If you use JSONP + https on the appspot domain, your users will not see that your site is secure, and you will not be able to save cookies in a secure manner.  For us, the only solution was to expose the ugly appspot.com domain directly to our customers.  Google has been saying for a long time that SSL on custom domains is coming, but there's no date.

Edit for PS: if you don't need your customers to see a green https, and don't need to save cookies in a secure manner (maybe instead a secure-by-obscurity session key?), jsonp + https to *.appspot.com sounds like a clever solution that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid that exposing the appspot.com domain isn't an option, it's just too ugly.  I don't mind that much whether users see that the site is secure.  For example, Reddit does submit login info via HTTPS but the user doesn't see it.  I don't think there is any evidence that Reddit's adoption has been limited by their lack of *visible* use of HTTPS.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure that I can agree that you *must* use HTTPS for secure communication via HTTP, since you could always do the crypto manually in the JavaScript and on the server.  Of course, you're still vulnerable to MITM with the initial download of the JavaScript code, but I'm more concerned about Eve than Mallory.

Comment: If you don't want them to see the https, and you don't need to save secure cookies, then jsonp + https to appspot.com should work fine.  Maybe you could implement your own ssl with javascript, but you mentioned you want to avoid reinventing the wheel.  And... why bother, if it's going to be vulnerable to MITM anyway?  If anyone cares enough to eavesdrop, someone will eventually care enough to set up a MITM.

Comment: Oh, I didn't say that implementing SSL in JavaScript was smart, I just said it was possible :-)

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Now that you mention it, I've thought of another secure way to log in - one-time pads on usb sticks! Your users would have to come to your office to register and collect their stick, unfortunately, but you'd have the best security in the industry at practically zero computational cost! :p

Comment: Wow, instead of requiring them to come to your office, you could just host your own SSLed server for the sole purpose of distributing the one-time pads. You wouldn't need appengine performance for that since it would be very rare that users would need to get new pads, so you could just run something off your DSL with an SSL cert of your own.  You could even have a whole spin-off business providing one-time pads to businesses and customers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its really a good question and really need some in depth knowledge of cryptography.. This is an article i found interesting a couple of month ago.. They have a proposed solution using CRAM-MD5 a challenge-response authentication. Hope this could be helpful.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRAM-MD5

http://blog.stochastictechnologies.com/secure-authentication-over-http

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, fortunately I have a pretty decent understanding of crypto (Applied Cryptography is one of my favorite books ;), but surely you shouldn't have to reinvent the wheel just to get secure authentication?

Comment: :) But i didn't find any solid implementation of this approach. most of the times we prefer using https over http when we need authentication..

Comment: Yeah, I'm leaning towards JSONP over HTTPS